# Problema com posicionamento do formulário

Tags: delphi, c++-builder

Tenho uma aplicação que funciona da seguinte maneira: Existe um form principal e abro formulários "filhos" durante a execução, para cadastro, pesquisa, etc. A intenção é sempre abrir os formulários filho no centro do formulário principal, independente do tamanho do mesmo. Para isso uso o seguinte procedimento (no onCreate do form filho):

```
formulario->Left=(formPrincipal->pnlPrincipal->Width/2);
formulario->Top=(formPrincipal->pnlPrincipal->Height/2)-(formulario->Height/2);
```

Até o momento tudo certo, o formulário fica centralizado corretamente, como mostra a imagem a seguir:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao fechar o formulário filho, restaurar o form principal e abrir novamente o form filho, o seguinte problema ocorre:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O formulário filho é gerado na posição que foi gerado da primeira vez (com a janela maximizada).

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o  evento `OnCreate` é executado uma vez somente, quando o formulário é criado. Você deve colocar esse código no evento `OnShow`, que ocorre a cada vez que o formulário é exibido.

```cpp
void __fastcall Tformulario::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    formulario->Left = (formPrincipal->pnlPrincipal->Width/2);
    formulario->Top = (formPrincipal->pnlPrincipal->Height/2)-(formulario->Height/2);
}
```

Comment: Um dos motivos era esse do onCreate mesmo, mas o problema não era apenas isso. Eu estava pegando como referencia o tamanho de um panel. Para resolver o problema passei a utilizar o tamanho do form como referência, passei a utilizar o código no onShow e mudei a propriedade Position do form filho ara poDefault.

Comment: @JefersonLeonardo Até pensei em sugerir isso, mas você tinha mencionado que na primeira vez o *form* se posicionava corretamente, dai não citei isso. O `position`  do *form* filho não deveria ser `poMainFormCenter`?

Comment: A princípio tinha funcionado bem com **poDefault** vou refazer alguns testes aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: Então, fiz algumas pesquisas e testes. Para chegar ao que eu queria não precisava nem deste código feito no onShow. A posição do form filho não atualizava quando ele era fechado e iniciado novamente porque, pra isso, é necessário destruir o form e recriá-lo. E a propriedade position do form filho deve ser poMainFormCenter

Comment: @JefersonLeonardo Já que foi isso que resolveu, poste isso como resposta e aceite. Talvez ajude outras pessoas com problemas semelhantes. :)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta tem um tag DELPHI, logo, imagino que eu possa dar a resposta dentro deste contexto.

Para que um form apareça centralizado em relação a um outro form, é necessário que o Owner do segundo form seja o primeiro form e que o segundo form possua a propriedade **Position** configurada como **poOwnerFormCenter**.

Para criar um form, tendo como Owner um outro form, proceda como segue:

```
SegundoForm := TSegundoForm.Create(PrimeiroForm);
SegundoForm.ShowModal;
```

Usando a forma de criação acima, **SegundoForm** vai ser exibido na frente de **PrimeiroForm** e exatamente em seu centro.

Ao terminar de usar **SegundoForm**, lembre-se de destruí-lo completamente (Close e Free) ou usar **Action := caFree** no seu evento **OnClose**

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma propriedade para VCL Forms para centralizar nativamente o formulário **Position** **[poScrenCenter]**, como Abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]